# XAMPP MySQL service error with node js giving socket error

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp

I am trying to launch my application locally on MacOS. I am using XAMPP, with port number of 3306, unfortunately I am getting socket error after some time and server quits.

After starting node, it shows that it loaded, and that it should display data on the webpage, unfortunately it does not. Even if reloaded, it shows that query has been executed, but after about 30 seconds the service is terminated giving an error:

```
text: 'socket has unexpectedly been closed',
sql: null,
fatal: true,
errno: 45009,
sqlState: '08S01',
code: 'ER_SOCKET_UNEXPECTED_CLOSE'
```

I have tried using a different port: 3307, 8080 for mySQL but nothing helped. I have also tried closing MySQL on my OS. The service starts without any errors, and as mentioned before, it quits after about 30 seconds of running.

What could be the issue and where to look for causes?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server  ...